# Package equivalency search: Ubuntu libace-6 => Fedora

Tags: ubuntu, package, fedora, equivalent

Does anyone know if there is a Fedora package equivalent of the Ubuntu packages libace-6 and libace-dev?

Comment: I have no specific knowledge, but there may be a [licensing problem](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=450164) for this package to be included with Fedora.  There are other RPMs available (e.g., from [openSUSE Build Service](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/libraries:/ACE:/)) or you could build from [source](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/TAO.html).